# Build exe package (Portable) from an existing project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

I have developed a C++ Project using opencv libraries in Visual Studio.
How to make an exe portable installation package out of it by including all the libraries?

Comment: you should link the opencv library as a static library when compiling your project

Comment: And also link MSVC runtime as a static library

Comment: i have linked all the libraries.its working fine.

Comment: i want to make the application portable ie; into a single exe installer

Comment: What do you mean by saying "portable"? Self-contained, i.e. having no dependencies?

Comment: use Microsoft visual studio installer project and add your dll's and output of your project it will create  msi and exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should statically link the opencv library in your project. If you use Visual Studio 2010 you could refer to this link http://varuagdiary.blogspot.it/2012/12/static-linking-opencv-in-visual-studio.html for more details.